# Python mulitprocessing queue isn't keeping all the workers busy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, queue, multiprocessing

I have a pipeline that runs on a single core that I am trying to run hundreds of times in parallel over the 32 cores of an aws instance.  The hope is that once a run is complete, the next one will start. I have written a queueing script based on one I found online and it seems to work but the efficiency trails off as if some workers are not accepting new processes but some are.

Here is the main code from my script (not sure why the indents are not showing up when I cut and paste here - they are correct in my script and everything works - so I don't think that's an issue):

```
def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
try:
    for f in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        newPipe = Pipeline(PathtoFiles + testPipelineList, PathtoFiles, ('parallel',f)) 
        done_queue.put("%s - %s got %s." % (current_process().name, f, newPipe))
        log("%s - %s got %s." % (current_process().name, f, newPipe))
except Exception, e:
    done_queue.put("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, f, e.message))
    log("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, f, e.message))
return True

def log(string):
outfile = open('queue_gene_logfile' + testPipelineList,'a')
outfile.write(string + '\n')
outfile.close()

def main():
############### pipeline specific stuff 

infile = open(PathtoFiles + '/' + testPipelineList,'r')  #list of ogs of interest   
count = 0
for line in infile: #makes input files and appends the name of the file to li
    outfile = open(PathtoFiles+ '/FileLists_' + testPipelineList + '/list' + str(count),'w')
    li.append('list' + str(count))
    outfile.write(line)
    outfile.close()
    count = count + 1

############### queue stuff below
workers = 32
work_queue = Queue()
done_queue = Queue()
processes = []

for f in li: #for each file in FileLists
    work_queue.put(f)
work_queue.put('STOP')  #will iterate through the work queue until it comes to 'STOP'   

for w in xrange(workers):
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue)) # work queue is a list of args (FileList names) for each pipeline
    p.start()
    processes.append(p) #a list of processes to join
    #work_queue.put('STOP') #I don't know why this is here - seems like it will have many 'STOP's in the queue- moving it to above

for p in processes:
    p.join()

done_queue.put('STOP')
for status in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):
    print status


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

And here is a screenshot of the cpu usage monitor from amazon (I start a new run of 100 processes in the middle after the first 100 finished) - Ugh, I don't have enough reputation to post my image - it is here:
http://www.science.smith.edu/departments/Biology/lkatz/images/CPU_use.png

Can anyone see why my efficiency goes down so steadily?  Obviously, runs are being started after the initial 32, but not all cores are being used at all times.

Editing to add - I set up a 200 job run yesterday - at first, all 32 cores were running.  Now, although there are 70 jobs left to do, only 18 are running - according to top.  Not sure if there is any way I can find out what the cores are doing (if anything) or if there is anything I can do (even manually) to get the rest going.  Here's what top looks like.  Lots of sleeping/zombie jobs.  Are these the problem, maybe?

```
top - 13:33:01 up 6 days, 20:59,  4 users,  load average: 16.02, 16.05, 16.32
Tasks: 691 total,  17 running, 567 sleeping,  79 stopped,  28 zombie
%Cpu(s): 49.8 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 50.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem:    245742 total,    69853 used,   175889 free,     1981 buffers
MiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free,    35477 cached

   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                         
 69054 ubuntu    20   0  167m 157m 1272 R   100  0.1 210:06.19 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
  2281 ubuntu    20   0  127m 118m 1268 R   100  0.0 345:45.54 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 55524 ubuntu    20   0 99520  89m 1288 R   100  0.0 242:37.41 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 64499 ubuntu    20   0  164m 154m 1276 R   100  0.1 217:24.57 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 72964 ubuntu    20   0  140m 130m 1280 R   100  0.1 202:28.98 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 73077 ubuntu    20   0  173m 163m 1272 R   100  0.1 202:18.51 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 78482 ubuntu    20   0 92484  80m 1276 R   100  0.0 195:14.09 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 78497 ubuntu    20   0  104m  96m 1292 R   100  0.0 195:11.02 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 79501 ubuntu    20   0  134m 124m 1272 R   100  0.1 191:59.39 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 86534 ubuntu    20   0  135m 125m 1276 R   100  0.1  91:46.00 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 88892 ubuntu    20   0  111m 102m 1276 R   100  0.0  84:53.55 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 90763 ubuntu    20   0  102m  93m 1276 R   100  0.0  77:32.76 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 94270 ubuntu    20   0 60544  50m 1280 R   100  0.0  42:05.16 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 95210 ubuntu    20   0 73604  62m 1280 R   100  0.0  39:38.67 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
102045 ubuntu    20   0  112m  86m 1272 R   100  0.0   3:31.35 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 98813 ubuntu    20   0 76844  51m 1268 R   100  0.0  21:21.22 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
102046 ubuntu    20   0 19808 2148 1120 R     1  0.0   0:00.11 top                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2280 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
  4343 ubuntu    20   0 25580 1116  880 S     0  0.0   0:00.31 screen                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4350 ubuntu    20   0  134m  16m 3748 S     0  0.0   0:00.13 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4359 ubuntu    20   0  143m  24m 1884 S     0  0.0   8:02.44 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4360 ubuntu    20   0  145m  26m 1884 S     0  0.0   3:05.85 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4363 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:05.23 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4366 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:03.89 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4370 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:48.45 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4372 ubuntu    20   0  142m  23m 1860 S     0  0.0   4:40.39 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4376 ubuntu    20   0  143m  24m 1884 S     0  0.0   1:40.96 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4379 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:05.15 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4383 ubuntu    20   0  141m  22m 1884 S     0  0.0   0:39.52 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4386 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:11.20 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4388 ubuntu    20   0  146m  27m 1888 S     0  0.0   9:08.29 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4390 ubuntu    20   0  143m  24m 1888 S     0  0.0   3:56.54 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4392 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:02.82 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4396 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:56.10 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4401 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   1:20.73 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4405 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   1:59.12 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4408 ubuntu    20   0  141m  22m 1884 S     0  0.0   1:50.49 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4413 ubuntu    20   0  143m  24m 1880 S     0  0.0   2:12.69 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4420 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:22.77 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4424 ubuntu    20   0  144m  25m 1884 S     0  0.0   3:21.91 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4428 ubuntu    20   0  145m  25m 1884 S     0  0.0   3:22.17 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4431 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   2:14.93 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4434 ubuntu    20   0  141m  22m 1880 S     0  0.0   4:02.82 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4438 ubuntu    20   0  142m  23m 1880 S     0  0.0   2:46.69 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4443 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:05.89 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4446 ubuntu    20   0  143m  23m 1884 S     0  0.0   2:20.15 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4450 ubuntu    20   0  144m  25m 1884 S     0  0.0   2:50.68 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4453 ubuntu    20   0  143m  24m 1888 S     0  0.0   1:12.57 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4457 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:22.13 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  4461 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   0:51.41 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
  5688 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
  5689 ubuntu    20   0  148m 138m 1276 T     0  0.1 240:22.68 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
  8337 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
  8338 ubuntu    20   0  153m 144m 1280 T     0  0.1 236:11.93 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 10025 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  524 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 10026 ubuntu    20   0  137m 127m 1276 T     0  0.1 234:20.39 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 10043 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 10044 ubuntu    20   0  127m 117m 1276 T     0  0.0 233:17.22 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 12386 ubuntu    20   0 25580 1116  880 S     0  0.0   0:00.45 screen                                                                                                                                                                                          
 12433 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 12434 ubuntu    20   0 73660  64m 1292 T     0  0.0 160:00.80 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 14688 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 14689 ubuntu    20   0 88780  77m 1276 T     0  0.0 143:17.54 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 36470 ubuntu    20   0 25956 1744  968 S     0  0.0   0:59.78 screen                                                                                                                                                                                          
 36471 ubuntu    20   0 20904 3532 1860 S     0  0.0   0:00.43 bash                                                                                                                                                                                            
 45234 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 45235 ubuntu    20   0  116m  91m 1272 T     0  0.0  31:54.50 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 55523 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 64498 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 69053 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 71281 ubuntu    20   0 95004 1876  892 S     0  0.0   0:05.47 sshd                                                                                                                                                                                            
 71310 ubuntu    20   0 21356 3984 1860 S     0  0.0   0:00.36 bash                                                                                                                                                                                            
 72963 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 73076 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  524 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 78481 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 78496 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  524 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 79500 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  524 S     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 81682 ubuntu    20   0  4440  624  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 81685 ubuntu    20   0 94980  83m 1276 T     0  0.0  48:33.73 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 83916 ubuntu    20   0  4440  628  528 T     0  0.0   0:00.00 sh                                                                                                                                                                                              
 83917 ubuntu    20   0 65964  47m 1272 T     0  0.0  12:19.77 raxmlHPC                                                                                                                                                                                        
 84034 ubuntu    20   0 25844 1612  968 S     0  0.0   0:10.79 screen                                                                                                                                                                                          
 84035 ubuntu    20   0 20896 3524 1860 S     0  0.0   0:00.15 bash                                                                                                                                                                                            
 84089 ubuntu    20   0  134m  16m 3748 T     0  0.0   0:00.14 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
 84096 ubuntu    20   0  146m  27m 1860 T     0  0.0   3:07.70 python                                                                                                                                                                                          
 84097 ubuntu    20   0     0    0    0 Z     0  0.0   5:13.17 python
```

Comment: If you edit this, post some code of what you do, and how you do it and where it goes wrong.

Comment: I hit post accidentaly in the middle of writing - my question is complete now!

Comment: "target=worker", but you dont define "worker"? and you dont use the w that you define in "for w in xrange(workers)" ? and can you fix the indentation? you start with main, but you dont indent

Comment: What does the `worker` function look like?

Comment: OK - I thought I was being clearer by only posting the part with the queue - I added the worker.  I don't know why the indentation isn't working when I cut and paste - none of my definition lines look right here, but they are fine in the script.

Comment: 1) the "%s" format operator can cause problems, I suggest format, as in `mylog = multiprocessing.get_logger(); mylog.info('stuff {} and things {}'.format(var1, var2)`

2) consider using `get_logger()` vs print -- it's more reliable and automatically prints which proc you're using.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.get_logger

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example where the work to be done is defined in the function "hmmsearch". The objects to be worked on are defined in "bins". This will keep all 32 workers busy:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from tqdm import tqdm

def hmmsearch(bin): return bin.pfams.run(cpus=1)
bins = bt.merged.results.binner.results.bins

pool = Pool(processes=32)
iterator = pool.imap(hmmsearch, bins, chunksize=1)
i = 0

for result in tqdm(iterator, total=len(bins)):
    print "Done bin %s." % bins[i]
    i += 1
```

Comment: What is `bt`? I got here from an other question, I'm trying to do multi line updates of progress bars.

Comment: It's nothing in a particular, just a custom home-made object. The variable `bins` just needs to be a list or a tuple, the rest is just there as an example.